# Stripe destination charge issue

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I will explain my business logic here,

step 1. i use my stripe test api credentials in code

step 2. i provide shop site for shop owners (like shopify), where customers can purchase products from them using stripe

step 3. shop owners update their card details and their card token store in DB

step 4. when customers purchase 10 rupees product, i took 1 rupee as service fee and i transfer 9 rupee to shop owner stripe account

in old stripe api version i use charge like ,

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  'amount' => 100,
  'currency' => 'gbp',
  'customer' => "cus_AAAAA",
  'destination' => array(
    "account" => "shop_owner_account,
    "amount" => 1
  )
));
```

it worked well..

```
but suddenly i got error like 'destination account must have any one of legacy_payments or transfers'.
```

then i used like,

```
 $account = \Stripe\Account::create(array(
                    "type" => "custom",
                    "country" => "GB",
                    "email" => 'asdsad@gmail.com',
                    'capabilities' => [
                        'card_payments' => ['requested' => true],
                        'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
                    ]
                   
        ));
```

and used **Connect Onboarding for Custom accounts** to get business details

but still got payout error "Add a bank account or debit card to enable payouts."

i have to get bank details from shop owner ? is it mandatory ? , because i already got card details (token, carid)

how to achieve above in new stripe api using php stripe

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly set the Capabilities for your connected accounts: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-capabilities

Then you need to add a card or bank account to the Connected Account as well. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-debit-card-payouts

Comment: i had requested card payments and transfer capabilities while creating account, you can check my question

Comment: i got payout error "Add a bank account or debit card to enable payouts." i have to get bank details from shop owner ? is it mandatory ? , because i already got card details (token, carid)

Comment: Edited my answer.